# How to get Device Status Report on Busybox?;

Tags: terminal, escape-characters, busybox

I'm trying to get DSR on busybox (to get terminal size), but `echo '\x1b[6n'` does not report anything, it outputs `\x1b[6n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. To make [`echo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/echo.1.html) handle escape sequences you need to add the option `-e`. This isn't a speciality of the BusyBox shell, it applies to `bash` and other implementations, too.
2. Deducting from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465171/python-3-capture-return-of-x1b6n-0336n-e6n-ansi-sequence) the ANSI code should be `\x1b[6n`.

Additionally it may be a good idea to suppress the finishing newline. Putting it all together I think the call should look as follows:

```
echo -en "\x1b[6n"
```

## BusyBox limitations

Older versions of BusyBox [don't support `\e` and `\x` escape sequences in `echo`](http://www.herikstad.net/2013/06/busybox-limited-echo.html); in this case `\033` must be used. This seems to be fixed in 1.23.1.

Make sure to set the following in the configuration:

- *Busybox Settings*

  - *Busybox Library Tuning*

    - *Query cursor position from terminal* → enabled

## SSH/PuTTY limitations

SSH [swallows the returned position](https://superuser.com/questions/985437/ssh-escape-key-only-works-when-connection-is-stuck/985616#985616). To see the answer in your remote terminal you can use

```
echo -en "\e[6n"; cat
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> after that.

Comment: Sorry, missing `[` was a typo. I've tried both with or without `-e` and no success. I have no problem doing it on Linux, but when I copypaste the same code to Busybox, it does nothing. So this is Busybox specific problem.